# Push GITHUB artifact to server

Tags: github, github-actions, artifacts

I need some help. I have a .net4 website and in GITHUB actions i can do the build and create artifacts. I now want to use an action to push that artifact to a folder on my remote server. How on earth can i do that and trigger it from the GITHUB workflow after the artifact is built? Been googling this for hours and I'm just not finding it.
Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Copy via ssh](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/copy-via-ssh)
 GH Action. This action allows uploading files or directories to the remote server using SSH commection:

```yaml
- name: Copy single file to remote
  uses: garygrossgarten/github-action-scp@release
  with:
    local: your-artifact
    remote: remote-path/your-artifact
    host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
    password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will have a go at that asap and get back on here. Really appreciate the help

Comment: Hi @JohanGrobler, was my answer helpful to you? :)

Comment: I had to use FTP in the end. Simply could not get the above to work.
kevinpainchaud/simple-ftp-deploy-action@v1.2.1